# How to fix messy code when i use ssh?

Tags: server, ssh, vps

when I use the `ssh vps` command to connect my vps it shows like this:

[image: messy code]

it's not an encoding error. I used the `locale` command the result shows

On my client:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

On my server:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

and I try to use
`echo $TERM`
both the client and server show:

`xterm-256color`

`/root/.oh-my-zsh/themes/mikeh.zsh.theme` file

```
autoload -U add-zsh-hook
autoload -Uz vcs_info

# check-for-changes can be really slow.
# you should disable it, if you work with large repositories
zstyle ':vcs_info:*:prompt:*' check-for-changes true

add-zsh-hook precmd mikeh_precmd

mikeh_precmd() {                                                                                                                                       
    vcs_info
}

# user, host, full path, and time/date
# on two lines for easier vgrepping
# entry in a nice long thread on the Arch Linux forums: http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=521888#p521888
PROMPT=$'%{\e[0;34m%}%B..[%b%{\e[0m%}%{\e[1;32m%}%n%{\e[1;30m%}@%{\e[0m%}%{\e[0;36m%}%m%{\e[0;34m%}%B]%b%{\e[0m%} - %b%{\e[0;34m%}%B[%b%{\e[1;37m%}%~%{\e[0;34m%}%B]%b%{\e[0m%} - %{\e[0;34m%}%B[%b%{\e[0;33m%}'%D{"%a %b %d, %I:%M"}%b$'%{\e[0;34m%}%B]%b%{\e[0m%}
%{\e[0;34m%}%B..%B[%{\e[1;35m%}$%{\e[0;34m%}%B] <($vcs_info_msg_0_)>%{\e[0m%}%b '
PS2=$' \e[0;34m%}%B>%{\e[0m%}%b '
```

I added

`test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh"`

to my .zshrc file

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the actual text you see in your terminal (use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code). That way we can check exactly what non-printing characters you are showing. Also, please tell us what operating system you are connecting from and show us the actual output of `locale` on both machines.

Comment: Might also be a `TERM` problem. What `$TERM` set to?

Comment: echo &TERM and it shows "xterm"

Comment: Please make the edits I asked for. Also include the output of `echo $TERM` *on both machines*.

Comment: Well Sorry. I'm not familiar with the format

Comment: I know, that's why I asked for the edit. I wasn't trying to imply you did something wrong :) Please copy the text from your terminal though, if you copy it exactly, we can see what the weird characters are but we can't from the image.

Comment: Hmm, have you edited any of the configuration files on the remote machine from Windows? It looks like you might have some windows style line endings there.

Comment: `]1337;RemoteHost=root@KK-SGP.localdomain]1337;CurrentDir=/root]1337;ShellIntegrationVersion=5;shell=zsh#`

This is the text I have copied from my terminal.
Hmm in fact the vps is mainly serve work for my MacBook.  But now it has been broken so I have to use Ubuntu to do some work.

Comment: By the way, If I try to use character ui. everything is OK

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra information. It is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Also, comments can be deleted with no warning. Mac? Ah-ha! That could explain it too. Can you post your `root/.oh-my-zsh/themes/mikeh.zsh-theme` file? Or, can you tell us what config files you might have edited from your mac?

Comment: well I'll add it to my question